# How can I insert multiple split string in single insert query

Tags: mysql, sql

create the following table

```
Declare @APS nvarchar(1000)='1,1,1.5,1.791'
,@cluster nvarchar(1000)='0150,0150,001,0382'
,@style nvarchar(1000)='696707-018,696707-018,696707-018,696707-018'


CREATE TABLE #temptable (
ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
stylecolor varchar (500) NOT NULL ,
APSDev varchar (250)  NULL,
ClusterID varchar(1000) Null
)
```

Here I need to insert values

```
Insert into #temptable  (stylecolor, ClusterID, APSDev)
select  item  from  [<table name>]. dbo.SplitString(@style,',') 
select  item  from  [<table name>].dbo.SplitString(@cluster,',')
select  item  from  [<table name>]. dbo.SplitString(@APS,',')
```

Getting error:

```
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the 
insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT 
columns.
```

Comment: That makes it seem like the id column is requiring something. Can you insert NULL for the ID column?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need commas  at the ends of the second and third lines?